# Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001 with new layout

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, android-emulator

I'm trying to use adapter for my own list, but with adding of listview_row.axml which is shown below, to layout, with debug when I'm trying to run my application I got message from emulator "Unfortunately Android App has stopped" and Unhandled Exception from Visual Studio:`System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` and `Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f030001`

Not sure what is wrong here:

MyListWievAdapter.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Android_App1
{
    class MyListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
    {
        private List<string> mItems;
        private Context mContext;

        public MyListViewAdapter(Context context, List<string> items)
        {
            mItems = items;
            mContext = context;
        }
        public override int Count
        {
            get { return mItems.Count; }
        }

        public override long GetItemId(int position)
        {
            return position;
        }

        public override string this[int position]
        {
            get { return mItems[position]; }
        }

        public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View row = convertView;

            if(row == null)
            {
                row = LayoutInflater.From(mContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.listview_row, null, false);
            }

            TextView textName = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textName);
            textName.Text = mItems[position];

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity.cs

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Android_App1
{
    [Activity(Label = "Android_App1", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        private List<string> mItems;
        private ListView mlistView;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            mlistView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);

            mItems = new List<string>();
            mItems.Add("Name1");
            mItems.Add("Name2");
            mItems.Add("Name3");

            MyListViewAdapter adapter = new MyListViewAdapter(this, mItems);

            string indexerTest = adapter[1];
            mlistView.Adapter = adapter;

        }
    }
}
```

and in layout folder:

listview_row.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <TextView
        android:text="Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/textName" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Main.axml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you debugged your code to figure out what is throwing a NRE?

Comment: @Jon Douglas Hello, yes but it is all I got, given exception. maybe I need to look into logcat. Since I'm a newbie with xamarin and android, not sure, what I have to check and how to read device_log, maybe Output_from_build or Xamarin_Diagnostics to figure out

Comment: I have completely copied your code, it works fine. Please refer to the [github link](https://github.com/mikexxma/AndroidListView_CustomerAdapter)

Comment: @ Mike Ma Hello, maybe something wrong with my emulator, now it is checked as Android_Accelerated_x86 (Android 6.0 - API 23) because your code is completely same, so possibly I should to install Xamarin Android Player developer.xamarin.com/releases/android/android-player but even this, content of error looks different like if something is null or just out of set, can't get what

Comment: @nikorio I didnot install the `Xamarin Android Player` and note that the Xamarin Android Player has been deprecated.  I am using google emulator from android sdk.